# How to debug "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I can't figure out which part of the code causes this.
I enabled "Pause on caught exceptions", but it doesn't pause. It just fails.

One interesting thing I might point out is that this event happens exactly when the main JS file is done downloading:

[image]

Another funny thing is that this app works flawlessly in Chrome Canary, Firefox, and Safari.

Ask away. I'll provide any additional relevant info I might be missing.

Comment: Can you please post your code? The dev-tool does show you the file the error occurs in. With no code we can only guess. This kind of error occurs when you call a function recursively with no exit condition, you may start looking for functions referencing themself. Also you said it works in most browsers? What browser are you using?

Comment: @PatrickHollweck It's a 50K loc project. I wish I knew which piece of code is to blame. Anyway, don't you think endless recursions would show up in the other browsers? I wouldn't put my money there.

Comment: I see. Sure it would happen in other browsers too, but there must be something different with this bundle since the browser should execute the code exactly the same...You can try adding a breakpoint / debugger statement at the start of the code and then just step through the code until you get the error

Comment: Try to pretty print the code portion where the error occurs to get an idea what module is causing this. Try to pack the application without minification. This error might by a symptom of long loading times (is caching active, does happen reproducible on all operating systems?). If you click "index:1" do you see your index page or your code (it might be Chrome code or an extension code)? Speaking of extensions: try disabling extensions. Does the application start with dev tools off? Do Firefox and others log things to the console where Chrome fails with this error?